# Taylor Series of $ f(x) = \frac{5}{3-6x} $

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion

I am trying to get the Taylor series at $x_0 = 0 $ of $ f(x) = \frac{5}{3-6x} $. I thought about using the modified geometric series $  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 5(-6x)^{k} $ . But I guess that isn't quite right because $\mid q \mid=(-6x)$ might be $ \geq 1 $ and I am missing the 3 in the denominator.

Thanks.

Comment: Write $f(x) = \frac{5}{3}\frac{1}{{1 - 2x}}$ and assume $|x|<\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that$$f(x)=\frac53\times\frac1{1-2x}=\frac53\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^nx^n$$if $|x|<\frac12$. But$$\frac53\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{5\times 2^n}3x^n$$and this is the Taylor expansion of $f$ centered at $0$.